# Использование _G и _ENV

Tags: lua

Я знаю: `_G` - окружение единое для всех модулей, файлов, блоков кода и т.д.,
`_ENV` - частное для каждого.

Увы, нюансы их использования я не совсем понял. (То ли я дурак, то ли книга не очень)

1. `_ENV` уникально только для каждого модуля\файла или для каждого блока, будь то функция, цикл, `do`/`end` и т.д. ?
2. По умолчанию `_ENV` присваивается `_G`?
3. Доступны ли переменные `local` в `_ENV`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 и 2: судя по `luac -l -l`, `_ENV` есть upvalue (т.е. забита для каждой функции, менять никто не запрещает), и да, по умолчанию она равна `_G`. По факту, как ясно из того же `luac -l -l`, весь доступ к "глобальным переменным" (точнее, свободным именам), идёт через `_ENV`.
3. Нет, не доступны. Вы же их не видете в `_G`, они на то и локальные.
**UPD**: что важно, это всё начинается в lua 5.2, в 5.1 такого нет.

P.S.: как раз моё по теме: http://goo.gl/E3d5Zb.